# How to make a lambda function friend of a class?

Tags: c++, lambda, friend

I was trying to make a class that takes as argument in the constructor a lambda function, and I want this function to be friend with the class. The code for the class looks like this:

```
using func = std::function<void(void)>;    

class foo
{
public:
    foo(func f)
    {
        this->f = f;
    }

    func f;
private:
    int value_I_want_to_modify; //an int I want to change from the function I've passed in the constructor
}
```

And in the `main()` I would write something like this:

```
int main()
{
    //this will give an error because I cannot access private members from outside class
    foo v
    {
        [&v](void) { v.value_I_want_to_modify = 0 };
    }
}
```

Now I would like the function to be friend with the class but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: How about just passing the int in by reference to the lambda instead?

Comment: Letting any old lambda be your friend is a fancy way of making *every* class your friend, since they can all just create lambdas and modify your class' guts. You may as well make all your member variables public.

Comment: A lambda is supposed to be a throw away thing.  If you need it enough where you need friendship then IMHO you need a full fledged named object and not a lambda.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Sorry, I've typed f instead of v in the lambda, it was an error

Comment: @jaggedSpire that's the meaning really, I'm trying to create a simple container class to mime the behaviour of C# properties with a similar sintax, so letting it being modified by any function by setting is a setter is part of the design.

Comment: If you want to program in C#, program in C#. Don't try to butcher C++ to pretend you're programming in C#. Properties violate encapsulation and the principle of "Tell, Don't Ask" anyway.

Comment: No, you can't add properties to C++. You are not the first to try and unfortunately not the last. If there was any loophole we would have about 40000 libraries that implement them by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to make a lambda function friend of a class?

You cannot. It's a catch-22 problem.

---

If you define the lambda function before defining the class, you can't access the member variable of the class.

```
using func = std::function<void(void)>;    

class foo;

// Trying to define the lambda function before the class.
// Can't use f.value_I_want_to_modify since foo is not defined yet.
auto lambda_function = [](foo& f) { f.value_I_want_to_modify = 0;}

class foo
{
   public:
      foo(func f)
      {
         this->f = f;
      }

      func f;
   private:
      int value_I_want_to_modify;
};

int main()
{
    foo v{lambda_function};
}
```

---

If you define the lambda function after defining the class, you can't make the lambda function a friend of the class.

```
using func = std::function<void(void)>;

class foo
{
   public:
      foo(func f)
      {
         this->f = f;
      }

      func f;
   private:
      int value_I_want_to_modify;
};

int main()
{
   foo f
   {
      // Can't make the lambda function a friend of foo
      // since it cannot be declared before the class definition.
      [&f](void) { f.value_I_want_to_modify = 0;}
   }
}
```

---

The easiest work around is to modify the lambda function to accept an `int&` as argument and modify its value.

```
#include <functional>

using func = std::function<void(int&)>;

class foo
{
   public:
      foo(func f)
      {
         this->f = f;
         this->f(value_I_want_to_modify);
      }

   private:

      func f;
      int value_I_want_to_modify;
};

int main()
{
   foo v{ [](int& out) { out = 0;} };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a lambda a friend since (by definition) you cannot name its type (which you need for a friend declaration).

Comment: No way I can make the variable f a friend in some way?

Comment: @MauroF. A variable cannot be a friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make an arbitrary `std::function` a friend, because you don't know when you write the friend declaration what its value is.

You can't make a lambda a friend either, as Jesper says.

What you can do is pass (by reference) your internal state to the function when you call it.

If you have more than one internal member you want to expose, you can wrap them in a structure to keep the argument list manageable.

eg.

```
class foo
{
public:
    struct state {
        int value;
        // any other internal values here
    };

    foo(std::function<void(state&)> fun) : f(fun) {}
    void run() { f(s); }

private:
    state s;
    std::function<void(state&)> f;
};
```

If you really want a nullary (zero-argument) function at your call sites, you can [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the argument first:

```
class foo
{
    // ...
    foo(std::function<void(state*)> fun) : f(std::bind(fun, &s)) {}
    void run() { f(); }

private:
    state s;
    std::function<void(void)> f;
};
```

(note in the second version, I just passed a pointer to internal state to avoid `reference_wrapper`).